# Hide row in excel and maintain table format

Tags: microsoft-excel, format

I'm hidding a row using VBA when a cell is selected.
The problem is that when I hide the row the colors of the table format mess up.
Any way to keep the table format updated when hidding a row?
Thanks in advance

You can see an example in the pictures, table colors mess up when I hide Row 45.
EDIT:This is my code... when I click cell C44 it changes from red to green or backwards, and hide or unhide row 45.

```
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C44")) Is Nothing Then
    If Range("C44").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
    Range("C44").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Rows("45").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    GoTo FIN_C44
    End If
    If Range("C44").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then
    Range("C44").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Rows("45").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    GoTo FIN_C44
    End If
End If
End If
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMTSh.jpg)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH4Py.jpg)

Comment: What is your VBA code? Could you post online the spreadsheet?

Comment: Code added in edited question.

Comment: Interesting,  I see if I hide say every second "white" line in an Excel table manually (not VBA), Excel automatically reapplies the one white-one blue formatting after the "hide" action. It *may* be that your own color formatting is interfering. Can you do a test to see if you only hide a table row via VBA, does Excel still correct the color banding? If so, perhaps you need to hide, doevents / redraw / screenupdate toggle - then set your red/green formatting. *Maybe*...